Encoding List Values for Custom Geometry Node Attributes: Seeking Solutions and Insights
For a personal project, I'm seeking guidance on transferring values stored in a list to a custom attribute within geometry nodes. I've encountered a challenge due to the limitations of BMesh, which doesn't support strings. Consequently, I can't employ a string format like "1;2;3;4;5" to represent my list, where each value is separated by a semicolon.
My workaround involves encoding the list values into a single integer. For instance, if my list is [1;4;6;15], I encode it as the integer 101040615. Each pair of digits in this integer corresponds to a value in the list (01, 04, 06, and 15 in this case). The leading 1 is necessary to ensure that every two digits are correctly interpreted, preventing misinterpretation like in the case of 01040615 (which would become 1040615). This approach functions well for lists with up to three pairs of values. However, when the list exceeds this length, issues arise, particularly with floating point operations in geometry nodes.
To overcome this limitation and extend the list length, one potential solution is to separate the tens and units digits. This would enable lists of up to seven elements.
What I am doing is to store data in a mesh, then it is duplicated as instance in GN and each instance has different features. In the screenshot you see 2 meshes, which are the same. The one on the left has GN off, where the other has GN on: is an extrusion, duplicated as instance multiple times, with different features, as height, colour, number of repetition, colour, which are all stores in the parameters assigned to the mesh.


This is an XY Question. What are you actually trying to do? Why do you want to store strings on geometry?

String are the easiest way to store data, like in a python list, but as I said I am happy using integers.
What I am doing is to store data in a mesh, then it is duplicated as instance in GN and each instance has different features.
In the screenshot you see 2 meshes, which are the same. The one on the left has GN off, where the other has GN on: is an extrusion, duplicated as instance multiple times, with different features, as height, colour, number of repetition, colour, which are all stores in the parameters assigned to the mesh.
https://ibb.co/GthrgGc
I hope that it clear now

Please edit your original question to add more information, including picture, instead of posting as a comment. It is easier for your reader to get all information in one place, not browsing comments.

Do you store this named attribute in Instance domain ? Could you use two colours for example to store up to 8 short unsigned int(s) (0-255) ? Or even more ?

Thank you @StefLAncien for editing the post for me.
The attributes are stored in the mesh (with python) and then read in GN.
Colours are stored either in vertices or face corners, but I need to store data in faces. But it was an interesting suggestion
